# Kinetic, potential and mechanical energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

When i drop an object, from 10 m, how much will the kinetic energy and the potential energy be, what I've come to, is that they aren't equal because the potential energy is converting to kinetic energy, am I wrong in assuming that? And if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption would be valid if we neglected the effect of friction. However, if we were to take into account friction, some energy is lost as work done to overcome friction. So by energy conservation, $E_P=\frac{mv^2}{2}+\int_{0}^{10}F\cdot dx$ where F is the resistive force and $E_P$ is the initial gravitational potential energy.